# как задать условие PHP

Tags: php

Как через if проверить есть ли в ShowViewContent('sotbit_seometa_bottom_desc'); какой-нибудь текст, если нет то в else вывести  (сео-текст) ?
Как это пока выглядит на сайте

```
<?$APPLICATION->ShowViewContent('sotbit_seometa_bottom_desc');//вывод нижнего описания?> 
<?echo $arSection["~UF_CATALOG_HTML"];//сео текст?>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, вам лучше сео текст сразу добавить в шаблон, где создается вывод для блока `sotbit_seometa_bottom_desc`.

Answer (score -1):

Что то типа того

```
<?php if(isset($APPLICATION->ShowViewContent('sotbit_seometa_bottom_desc'): ?>
  <?php echo $APPLICATION.... ?>
<?php else: ?>
  your seo text
<?php endif; ?>
```